# Emacs spacing format is inconsistent with my setup

Tags: whitespace, tabs, align

emacs version: GNU Emacs 26.3
using specman_mode.el

most of the company uses gvim, i am using emacs, so the alignment are a bit different.
but, when i open the file with emacs -Q, the alignment is actually good.
so i created a dummy file to check:

the requested end result:

```
unit new_temp {
    check_port        : in method_port of type is instance;
    check_port_here   : in method_port of type is instance;
    check_port_do_not : in method_port of type is instance;
};
```

i started with:
unit new_temp {
check_port : in method_port of type is instance;
check_port_here : in method_port of type is instance;
check_port_do_not : in method_port of type is instance;
};

i opened emacs -Q, and ran the following command (while selecting the lines): `M-x align-regexp RET \(\s-*\): RET`
(Note that align-regexp DOES NOT request further parameters

**now the interesting part**

if i open it with emacs -Q, i get the required result

```
unit new_temp {
    check_port        : in method_port of type is instance;
    check_port_here   : in method_port of type is instance;
    check_port_do_not : in method_port of type is instance;
};
```

if i open the file with normal emacs or gvim, i get :

```
unit new_temp {
    check_port      : in method_port of type is instance;
    check_port_here : in method_port of type is instance;
    check_port_do_not   : in method_port of type is instance;
};
```

if i try to re-align it while in normal emacs mode, nothing changes

i tried to change font, disable specman-mode, nothing worked.
**how can i find the issue ?**

see attached image for another example with .vs file

[image: emacs -Q , emacs, gvim]

**EDIT: Following your advice** here is a screenshot with the different fonts
[image: Sans vs Monospace]

Comment: In the Emacs screenshot, part of the misalignment happens when the line number goes from one to two digits, so it is partly an artifact of that. Turn off line numbers and see if the problem is still there.

Comment: @NickD you are correct in noticing that, but the issue is the Font.
i added a comment on the answer below, it happens when i change the Monospace font to Sans
i added new screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your configuration and customizations are stored in your emacs init file. The usual advice is to bisect this file: comment half of it out and see if the problem goes away. If it does, then the problem is in the half that you commented out, otherwise it must be in the part that you did not. You can repeat this process on smaller and smaller chunks of your init file until you find the one thing that causes your problem. (Running `emacs -Q` is equivalent to commenting out the whole file.)

Of course, you have to maintain correct syntax throughout so you might not be able to divide exactly in half each time.

Comment: ok, thank you. i will try this.

Comment: after checking, it is caused when i change the Font. 
if i use Monospace, everything is OK, when i change it to any other Sans font, the above issue happens

Comment: Oh, that’s perfectly ordinary then. You can’t expect to reliably line things up except in a monospaced font.

Comment: apparently so, but this is not something i new before! this is the first time i see such a thing.
now i am trying to understand what does Fixed width means, and everything related to fonts. but that is for another thread.
thank you :)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font

Comment: Thank you!! That explains a lot. Thank you :))